# Dynamic Sub Domain Routing with NGINX And laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, nginx

I have setup sub domain routing with nginx and laravel for my development site, but for some reason when i access the site with ***[www.lunch.test](http://www.lunch.test)*** it works but when i access the site with ***companyA.lunch.test*** it doesn't work.

Below is my nginx lunch.conf file. I will be on stand by for solution.

```
    listen 80;
    server_name www.lunch.test lunch.test *.lunch.test;
    root /var/www/html/lunch/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log on;
    error_log  /var/www/html/lunch/storage/logs/error.log error;
    access_log  /var/www/html/lunch/storage/logs/access.log  main;
    
    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;      

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300; 
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all viewers, i was able to resolve the issue by mapping the domain name to the ip address in `/etc/hosts` file like so,
`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      companyA.lunch.test`